# SignalR Issue with .Net Core 5.0 migration, app.UseSignalR -> app.UseEndpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, signalr, http-status-code-401

I've migrated from Net core 3.1 to 5.0, but I'm not able to get signalR to connect after the update. I'm getting a 401 error whenever It tries to connect to the hub.

Error Log

```
2020-12-17 15:47:07.351 -08:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
2020-12-17 15:47:07.351 -08:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 POST 
https://blah.blah.org:5001/range/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0 - 401 0 
- 4.4068ms
2020-12-17 15:47:12.355 -08:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/2 POST 
https://blah.blah.org:5001/range/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
2020-12-17 15:47:12.355 -08:00 [INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

Configure function items in Startup.cs

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCookiePolicy();  
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
      endpoints.MapHub<Hubs.RangeHub>("/range");
});
```

javascript

```
connection = connection || new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/range")
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();

async function start()
        {
            try
            {
                await connection.start();
                console.log("SignalR Connected.");
            } catch (err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                setTimeout(start, 5000);
            }
        };

start();
```

The Hub is using the [Authorize] Attribute

```
[Authorize]
public class RangeHub : Hub
```

I'm also seeing a disturbing amount of exceptions in the debug output in visual studio when I run the app that could be contributing to the issue:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in 
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in 
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Is anyone else running into this issue? I've spent a few days trying different things, but short of reverting back to core 3, I don't know what else to try.

-- UPDATE -- After a couple more days of playing around with it I tried reverting back to core 3.1, but left the change of app.UseSignalR to app.UseEndpoints that 5.0 enforces. It looks like that change is the main problem I'm having trouble getting around. It brings with it some authorization changes I'm unfamiliar with and can't find any information on:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<Hubs.RangeHub>("/range");
});
```

The change over from app.UseSignalR to those lines. This is only being used for managing user sessions. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How do you assign `loginToken`? The backend could not valid the tocken.

Comment: @user1986237 I'm not trying to use jwt for user sessions anymore. I'm trying to figure out why standard cookie auth for signalr stopped working in 5.0. I think it has to do with the switch to endpoints, I'm just not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a crappy week. The problem was that app.UseAuthorization(); and
app.UseAuthentication(); were in the wrong order. They needed to look like this:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Frustrating when the solution is that simple.